# Fortran read hexadecimal from file as ASCII

Tags: fortran, ascii

I need to use a bit old program written in fortran-77. This program reads 10 variables from text file in hex format

```
open (2,file=filename, status='old', iostat=ios)
read (2,1) my_variables
1 format (/(10z8))
```

And one variable is string (character*4) and I want to get smth like '414E4950' in hex to 'ANIP'. 
But the problem is when I try to read data from file I get an error.

> Fortran runtime error: Value overflowed during integer read

How can I solve it?

EDIT

Looks like I simplified the problem too much.
I have data file which looks like:

```
DATA_BLOCK_NAME

     3D3       1    23BE       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       041200000414E4950       03F800000       0      16    23BF       0       0
       0       0       0       0       0       041200000414E4950       03F800000
       0      1E    23C0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

And I want to read this data to variables.

```
        read (2,1) obj_num,((var_1(j,i),j=1,7),(var_2(j,i),j=1,3),var_3(i),
 +      name(i),var_4(i),var_5(i),var_6(i),i=1,obj_num)
```

obj_num is integer*4
var_1 is array of integer*4
var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6 are arrays of reals
but (!) name is array of strings (character*4)

As you can see in data file in every 12'th value coded object name ('414E4950' to 'ANIP' for example) and I want to store it as string.

P.S.

To repair program I wrote a little but very dirty fix.

```
 read (2,1) obj_num,((var_1(j,i),j=1,7),(var_2(j,i),j=1,3),var_3(i),
 +      tmp(i),var_4(i),var_5(i),var_6(i),i=1,obj_num)

  do j=1,numcn
     do i=1,4
        tmp_name( i:i ) = CHAR(MOD(tmp(j), 256))
        tmp(j) = RSHIFT(tmp(j), 8)
     end do
     ccns(j) = tmp_name
  end do
```

Where tmp is integer*4 array and tmp_str is character*4
It's ugly but working.

Comment: What do you mean by "one variable is string"?  The `Z` edit descriptor is for numeric types.  Perhaps you can show what `my_variables` really is, and how it/those are declared?

Comment: As i undestrand this statement (i am a junior in lab and don't know fortran ;( ) read (2, 1) read ten numerical values and try to assign it to variables in list. Every variable in list has numerical type (integer*4 or float*8) but one has character*4 type.

Comment: Things get a little complicated because `Z` isn't in Fortran 77.  If you really have a program which claims to be for a F77 compiler, it may mean that it allows a different interpretation of `Z`.  However, in standard Fortran, `Z` may be used for input only with integer, real and complex variables.  The list of variables must match the format: if you want to read in to a character variable, you must match that variable with a suitable entry in the format.

Comment: Thank you! So i need to change read format, am I right? And how can i decode hexademical value to string?

Comment: Perhaps you should/could explain more fully what you are trying to do.  Fortran can read and write hexadecimal values into and out of integer variables, with remarkable ease.  It can even write an integer value into a string containing the hexadecimal digits for further processing as a string.  But I just don't understand what you mean by phrases such as *decode hexademical value to string*.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because `my_variables` is declared as and integer an your format doesn't look quite correct. Hence it is trying to read integers from the file, not hex. And just by chance, the value `414E4950` read as integer is just a huge number which Fortran cannot handle. Hence the error.

I would change the format to `1 format (10z8)`. The slash indicates that the end of the current record is reached and skips everything else jumping to a new line. So using it at the beginning of the format specification doesn't look quite right.

Also, to read 10 variables with different data types you should use eg:

```
read (2,1), my_string_variable, my_variables(1), my_variables(2), my_variables(3), my_variables(4), my_variables(5), my_variables(6), my_variables(7), my_variables(8), my_variables(9)
```

Finally, you will probably need to use the `DATA` statement.

Comment: I don't disagree with most of this answer but hex `414E4950 ` is only decimal `1095649616` which is within the range of signed 32-bit integers.

Comment: What I meant is that since the format was incorrect, it was trying to read integers, not hex. Therefore `414E4950` read as integer is not within the range.